# Including .h file from other directory

Tags: c

Let's say I've got directory **a/** with two other directories **b/** and **c/** in it.

**main.c** is in **b/** but I need to include to it **headers.h** file which is in **c/**, is there any way I can go one directory up from **b/** to **a/** and then include **headers.h** like this?

```
#include "c\headers.h"
```

I want to avoid specyfying the whole path

```
#include "C:\Program Files\a\c\headers.h"
```

so that wherever **a/** is moved, **main.c** will still work fine

Comment: You can use the double dot notation to go up one directory level. In your case you can use `#include "..\c\headers.h"`

Comment: Thank You! That was just exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Most C compilers accept the `-I` [preprocessor option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), adding some directory to the include search path.

So configure your build (probably your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, e.g. your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) if you use [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) to add such a flag to the compilation command.